# Do Pdb files contains public function's arguments name?

Tags: c++, native, pdb-files, dbghelp

I need to look up function argument names of public methods. Types are easily available from PDB symbols and DIA symbols, but is there any way out by which we can trace and pull out function argument names as well?

I am concerned with the native pdb symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the LocalsByAddr.cpp sample [here](http://www.debuginfo.com/examples/dbghelpexamples.html).